# rspec controller test error undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, bdd

I'm new to Rspec and I am trying to get into the whole BDD mindset, so I'm pretty stumped about this error. I have have rails engine that I am trying to test. Here is the bulletin controller. Basically before any action I want to populate the list of courses.

```
class BulletinsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_courses

  def new
    @bulletin = Bulletin.new(author_id: @user.id)
  end

 ...

 private
 def get_courses
   if @user.has_role? :admin
     @course_list = Course.all.sort_by(&:start_date)
   ...
   end
 end
```

The application controller has some methods that I want run on each request. I am using devise in the host app so I have access to the current_user method

```
class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_user
  ...
  def get_user
    @user = current_user
  end
  ...
end
```

And here is the spec I am trying to run:

```
describe BulletinsController do
  routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }
  before { controller.stub(:authenticate_user!).and_return true }
  before { controller.stub(:get_user).and_return (@user = create(:user)) }

  describe "GET #new" do
    it "assigns a new bulletin to @bulletin" do
      bulletin = create(:bulletin)
      controller.stub(:get_courses)
      get :new
      assigns(:bulletin).should eq(bulletin)
    end
  end 
end
```

When I try to run the spec, I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass
```

I understand that I am getting this because @user is not defined when it is called in the bulletin building; however I thought that the before block in the spec would define the @user variable after stubbing out the :get_user filter. When I test the factories in the console, everything seems to be created with the proper associations (bulletin -> author, bulletin -> course, etc).

I'm not sure what I'm missing as to why the @user variable is not being carried through to my controller code. Any insight and/or good tutorials for rspec would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess You also need to stub `current_user` and it will be enough (no need to stub `get_user`):

```
before { controller.stub(:current_user).and_return (@user = create(:user)) }
```

And i guess the good practice is to let user (if you need it more than once):

```
routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }
let!(:user) { create(:user) }
before { controller.stub(:current_user).and_return user }
```

If you need an access to private methods, you can try something like this:

```
subject.send(:current_user=, user)
```

Could be a `controller` instead of `subject`, not sure what version which supports.

Update. Actually, it's really tricky to test private methods. I checked that `current_user` in `devise` defines like:

```
def current_#{mapping}
  @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
end
```

So, you can try stub `warden.authenticate` to returns `user`:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Warden).to receive(:authenticate).and_return(create(:user))
```

Comment: Stubbing the current_user method worked. Thanks! Also, thank you for the extra info on the private methods

Answer (score 3):

Trying to stub out the methods that Devise could be using will be quite difficult unless you understand how Devise works.

The recommend way to test is to simply sign in the user using Devise test helper as per their documentation:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers

```
describe BulletinsController do
  routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }
  before { sign_in(user) }

  let!(:user) { create(:user) }

  describe "GET #new" do
    it "assigns a new bulletin to @bulletin" do
      bulletin = create(:bulletin)
      controller.stub(:get_courses)
      get :new
      assigns(:bulletin).should eq(bulletin)
    end
  end 
end
```

This way, you won't have to care about Devise methods and stubbing it. Just focus on testing your own method. :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was trying to avoid using the Devise test helpers because Devise is being used in another engine that plugs in to the main application. I don't think I can access the test helpers in that one, and I didn't want to set up devise in my test app.